# Google Sheets conditional combine, clear all cells in range, Loop. VBA to JS

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm translating VBA into a Google Sheets script, but am a loss on how to get past this loop through all rows in a single column hurdle.

I have a column which contains an **#OrdernNumber**, a **-State code**, a **First name**, and ***sometimes a Last name***, followed by an **empty cell**. I need to combine the First and Last names into the First name cell, and then clear the Last name cell below. This is illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image: Illustrative screenshot]

Column C and D in the screenshot reveal the pattern I used to construct my original VBA code:

```js
Sub WorkingCombineAndClearLoop()

Dim Rngcell                 As Range

For Each Rngcell In Range("B1:B100")
  'if first character is #
  If left(Rngcell.Value, 1) <> "#" _                    
  'and if first character is -
  And left(Rngcell.Value, 1) <> "-" _
  'and if cell is not blank then
  And Rngcell.Value <> "" Then                          
        'combine left cell
        Rngcell.Value = Rngcell.Offset(0, -1).Value _   
        'with bottom left cell
        & " " & Rngcell.Offset(1, -1).Value
        'then clear below cell
        Rngcell.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Following is my annotated JavaScript code. Because I can't get the loop working yet, I've had to change the code logic a bit:

```js
    function workingCombineAndClearNoLoop() {

    //get active spreadsheet, sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
    //determine row count
    var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A:A").getLastRow();

    //if A1's first character is not # AND
    if (s.getRange('A1').getValue().substring(0,1) === "#" && 
        //if A2's first character is not ' AND
        s.getRange('A1').offset(1, 0).getValue().substring(0,1) === "-" ) {
        //Set the value of A2 to...
        s.getRange('A1').offset(2, 1).setValue(
        //A2 cell content + " " + A2 cell content (concatenate)
        s.getRange('A1').offset(2, 1).getValue() + " " +
        s.getRange('A1').offset(3, 1).getValue())
        //and then clear A2
        s.getRange('A1').offset(3, 1).clearContent()
    };
    }
```

The following is where everything falls apart - **the loop.** I've only left the bare bones in this final copy of the code:

```js
function notWorkingCombineAndClearWithLoop() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A:A").getLastRow();

//loop
//how to replace 'A1' with A[i]?, so that it loops through all cells in the column?
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  if (s.getRange('A1').getValue().substring(0,1) === "#" && 
      s.getRange('A1').offset(1, 0).getValue().substring(0,1) === "-" ) {
        s.getRange('A1').offset(2, 1).setValue(
        s.getRange('A1').offset(2, 1).getValue() + " " +
        s.getRange('A1').offset(3, 1).getValue())
        s.getRange('A1').offset(3, 1).clearContent()
        }
  };
}
```

*Note: I've completed Codacademy's JS course and several Google Sheets tutorials, and am pretty good at VBA, but I'm still swimming in circles with this. I've tried to follow many loop examples, using variables in place of A1. Because I can't find any working solution, I've left the non-functioning A1 as a simple placeholder.*

Comment: The JS code doesn't look to be JavaScript. By the other hand the code snippets aren't complete.

Comment: You are correct. In an attempt to simplify the VBA code and make it look a bit more familiar to JavaScript users as opposed to VBA users, I kind of screwed it up. I've been working on the code all morning and am making slow, steady progress...I will update this thread in a few hours if I hit a road block :)

Comment: @Rubén What do you think of the update? :D

Comment: I added the language tags to apply the correct syntax highlighting to each code block but in the preview it doesn't look to be working. Hopefully it will work fine after the edit is approved. Regarding language tags, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work

Comment: By the way, it's looking better and better. Regarding the last code block, the Google Apps Script shows that there are errors (missing `)` due to an extra `(` and a missing `}`). See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting.

Comment: @Rubén your language tags did not seem to take effect, so I updated the syntax highlighting (though I was only able to enable either universal VBA or universal JS highlighting, so went with the latter.

Comment: They didn't take effect because the related edit was rejected by some reviewers :(

Comment: Thank you @Rubén for finding my syntax errors with the ) and }. I've corrected those and now, I believe, the final step is to solve how to replace the s.getRange('A1') with a working variable in place of A1, such as s.getRange('A'[i]) or something like this. Small, steady steps :)

Comment: @Rubén maybe the reviewer had the same problem I did, which was that tagging the first code block as vb and the second/third as js was not working. I spent a solid 20 minutes (i think) trying to solve it, but without success...just a guess though.

Comment: The original version of the code in my answer was throwing an error because the loop index started in `0` and `A0` isn't a valid reference. The intention of my answer is to show how to use the `A1` notation to loop through the cells of a column in Google Apps Script. I corrected that. Anyway, it's up to you to use the A1 notation, the rowNum, colNum, of any other way of getting a range :).

Comment: Ah cool. I switched to notation (i + 1, 1) in place of (A + 1), which is all I could manage to make it work :) Thank you a ton @Rubén, sometimes people need a little push to keep making progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

> ```js
> //how to replace 'A1' with A[i]?, so that it loops through all cells
> //in the column?
> ```

Use

```js
'A' + i
```

## Explanation

getRange() has several forms, one of them use A1 notation reference. This is used in concordance with the Google Apps Script included in the question.

## Example

The main intention of below code is to show how to use the A1 notation to loop through the cells of a column in Google Apps Script.

---

There was some errors in the indexes. They were corrected.
Also changed the fourth line to reduce the rows to loop through and added a couple of lines.

---

```js
function editedNotWorkingCombineAndClearWithLoop() {

   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
   var numRows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
   /* 
    * use variables to reduce number of calls to Apps Script services
    * and improve readability
    */ 
   var range, substring1, substring2;

   //loop
   for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
      //Here is the magic        
      range = s.getRange('A' + i );
      substring1 = range.getValue().substring(0,1); 
      substring2 = range.offset(1, 0).getValue().substring(0,1); 
      if ( substring1 === '#' && substring2 === '-' ) {
        range.offset(0, 1).setValue(range.getValue()); 
        range.offset(1, 1).setValue(range.offset(1, 0).getValue());      
         range.offset(2, 1).setValue(
           range.offset(2, 0).getValue() 
           + " "
           + range.offset(3, 0).getValue()
         )
      }
   }
}
```